# Android memory leak in Handler

Tags: android, memory-leaks, handler, android-progressbar

This function update a custom progress with the count value in order to start in 10 seconds, stop at 0 and every millisecond update the progress to be fluid. (note that the "updateProgress" call a invalidate() function)

If I use the normal progress, it's ok, I didn't have memory leak, but if I use this code, the memory in the 'Android profiler' inspector start in 60mb but it increases and does not stop.

I need to use the custom progress.

There is a better way to implement it?

```
private void testing(){
    count = 10000;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (count > 0){
                updateProgress(count);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
            }
            count--;
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
}
```

Comment: why are you post every 1 millisecond ?

Comment: use 30-40ms not 1ms - but honestly you should use `Choreographer` or `TimeAnimator` for such things

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use handler every 100 millsecond (better 1 sec ) instead of 1 milli second

```
private void testing(){
    count = 10000;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (count > 0){
                updateProgress(count);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100); //100 millsecond
            }
            count--;
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
}
```

**2.** Make sure you remove the handler callback in onstop

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
   handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

Comment: I cant find the onStop function

Comment: are you in fragment or activity ?

Comment: i'm in activity

Comment: its one of the method in activity lifecycle like `onCreate`